# How do you install the latest enterprise edition with n98-magerun?

Tags: magento-enterprise, install, installation

I'm trying to figure out how to install the latest enterprise edition using n98-magerun. Can you install from a zip on the local filesystem using n98-magerun? Is the latest Enterprise Edition available on a git repository?

Comment: Just to make sure, you know that EE is a commercial product and so on? and you also looked how your Magento Account looks like (as a customer or a partner agency)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible.
See Wiki for instructions:

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/wiki/Magento-installer#add-own-magento-repositories

You can add new installer sources in your config.
n98-magerun uses an embedded composer which can handle i.e. git, zip or taballs as installation source.

You can find the default config here: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/blob/master/config.yaml

All your config will be merged with the dist config.

Comment: Magerun never fails to surprise me.