# Installing local tar.gz of magento enterprise with n98-magerun tool

Tags: magento-enterprise, install, install-script, installer

I have this in my .n98-magerun.yaml:

```
commands:
  N98\Magento\Command\Installer\InstallCommand:
    magento-packages:
      - name: magento-ee-1.14.2.1
        version: 1.14.2.1
        dist:
          url: file:///path/to/enterprise-1.14.2.1.tar.gz
          type: tar
```

I know that file is read since exception is thrown if yaml is malformed.
Still, for some reason, the command `n98-magerun.phar install` command still proceeds to download magento-ce-1.9.1.1. Note: my command line user running n98-magerun has full permissions on the tar.gz .

Reference for this configuration:
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/wiki/Magento-installer

Related question:
[How do you install the latest enterprise edition with n98-magerun?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6124/how-do-you-install-the-latest-enterprise-edition-with-n98-magerun)

**Any ideas on why this does not work?** I am guessing that something has changed which is not reflected in current documentation(?). Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Alternatively, advice on debugging the resulting magerun config array could help in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: For one thing, when running the n98 tool, if you do not specify the magentoVersion flag, the tool will ask you about the version, then you will be able to choose the tar.gz to install.